# How to align a button over top of a text input?

Tags: html, css

[Here's what I've got](http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/KDN8s/):

**HTML**

```html
<div class="combobox">
    <input type="text" value="" name="brand" class="text" id="brand">
    <span class="dropdown_btn"></span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```css
.combobox {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.combobox input {
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.combobox .dropdown_btn {
    width: 18px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

But it comes out like this:

[image]

I don't know where the gap is coming from; why isn't the text input snug against its container div like the blue button is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting the `vertical-align:top` to `input`

http://jsfiddle.net/KDN8s/4/

```css
.combobox {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.combobox input {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
}

.combobox .dropdown_btn {
    width: 20px;
    height: 24px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="combobox">
    <input type="text" value="" name="brand" class="text" id="brand">
    <span class="dropdown_btn"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this to add `vertical-align: middle;` to `.combobox .dropdown_btn` and remove it from the `combobox` class:

```
.combobox .dropdown_btn {
    width: 18px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: blue;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to apply `vertical-align: middle` to your inline elements:

```
.combobox {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.combobox input {
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.combobox .dropdown_btn {
    width: 18px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: blue;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

See: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/8GpxP/)

The `vertical-align` property is not inherited, so you need to specify it to any inline elements that you want to adjust.

Comment: @JoshC So did fujy !!!

Comment: By the way you don't need to add the vertical-align to `.combobox input`

Comment: @fujy Not quite.  Set `vertical-align: baseline` to `.combobox input` and you will see the blue motif shift vertically slightly. See: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/8GpxP/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
.combobox .dropdown_btn {
    width: 18px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: blue;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KDN8s/5/

Comment: That doesn't even work in the example you provided.

Comment: Why did you clear a float? You need to apply `vertical-align: middle` to the input field also since that one is aligned with the baseline by default.